# cast(SUBSTRING with decimal

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, numbers, substring, decimal

I have this line that works and gets my column into a number

```
       case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION('/DAY' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as numeric) when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as numeric)
            when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%SCHG%'  then cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as numeric)
            else 0
       end as Amt_Day
```

what can I add to this to make it come back with two decimal spots also. Right now it is whole numbers bring back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then CAST(cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION('/DAY' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as decimal(13,2)) as decimal(13,2))
     when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then CAST(cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as decimal(13,2)) as decimal(13,2))
     when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%SCHG%' then CAST(cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as decimal(13,2)) as decimal(13,2))
      else 0
end as Amt_Day
```

In general you have to CAST it like this:

```
CAST(yourField as decimal(13,2))
```

Comment: Do I put that under this line?

Comment: when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as numeric)

Comment: @Matt:- You can try like `CAST(cast(SUBSTRING(Auth_Amt FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN Auth_Amt) - 1) as numeric) as decimal(13,2))`

Comment: Aswesome. That kind of worked. What is happening is, My line was abstracting a number from the first part of a string. Example 26.50. My line was bringing back 27. (converting the 26.50 from text to numeric) but it rounded it to 27 when I brought it back. With your code it brought back 27.00. Is there a better way to do what I am talking about so It would bring back 26.50. It looks like it is rounding it and then I am turning it to a decimal so I am losing the change?

Comment: @Matt:- When you are converting it to numeric then probably its doing the rounding. So I think you need to make the change there. let me edit my answer

Comment: @Matt:- You are welcome. You can accept the answer if that helped you. (A right tick mark turns green when clicked)